# Force function caller decide which default value is used

Tags: python, parameter-passing, variable-assignment, default-value, function-call

Lets say I have the following function:

```
def myFun(a=None, b=None):
    print a, b
```

Now I call the function:

```
myFun("hi") # Case 1
>>>hi None

myFun(b="hi") # Case 2
>>>None hi

myFun(a="hi") # Case 3
>>>hi None
```

Is there a way to throw an exception if the function caller did not decide which variable the value "hi" is assigned to? That means I would like to have an exception in the 1st case but not in the 2nd and 3rd case. I use python 2.7.

Comment: yes, remove the de parameters and work it as keyword arguments, then it will be compulsory for the variable to be assigned as you wish and the first case shall raise an exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python3 you can specify [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/):

```
def myFun(*, a=None, b=None):
    print(a, b)

myFun('hi')
```

raises

```
TypeError: myFun() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

---

In Python2, as [Ricardo Silveira points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987702/force-function-caller-decide-which-default-value-is-used#comment63419684_37987702) you could use `**kwargs` to force all arguments to be keyword arguments.

```
def myFun(**kwargs):
    a, b = kwargs.get('a'), kwargs.get('b')
    print(a, b)

myFun('hi')
# TypeError: myFun() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_fun(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get("a", None)
    b = kwargs.get("b", None)
    # have your code here...
```

Then: `my_fun("hi")` shouldn't work...

Comment: Hmm this does not throw an exception in the first case.

Comment: TypeError: my_fun() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given), that is an exception, only that it was not you who wrote it exactly, but you can just wrap it in the caller method of my_fun

Comment: Sorry I don't get the exception with your code but with the code from unutbu I get it. Well I think this depends on my python version. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @user2177047: Ricardo Silveira's answer works. Make sure you call `my_fun("hi")` instead of `myFun("hi")` to test it however.

Comment: Damn you are right. I did't see the different function name and it still called my function although I commented it out. It was still in memory...

Comment: let's be pythonic guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually allow the user to provide any arguments they'd like by using **kwargs.

```
def myFun(**kwargs):
    print kwargs[a]
    print kwargs[b]
```

This will cause an error if a or b aren't defined, but they're not very helpful.

You can make your own errors by checking if the value exists. For example:

```
def myFun(**kwargs):
  if not kwargs.get(a):
    raise Exception('a is not here!')
  if not kwargs.get(b):
    raise Exception ('b is not here!')
  print kwargs[a], kwargs[b]
```

Comment: `NameError: global name 'a' is not defined`